# how to fix this error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/52/11847652/html/mastapps/wp-content/themes/couponpress/template_couponpress/_item.php on line 90

this is the link http://couponsgrabber.in/
http://hostgatorcouponcodesara.com

Comment: Umm also make sure to provide us the _item.php contents. Probably it's a theme error.

Comment: This is code  <?php if( get_option("couponpress_search_hover") == "off" get_option("display_myaccount_fav") != "no"){ ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the operator in your condition .. make sure what you need here and place your needed operator .. here the two example of `AND(&&)` and `OR(||)`

```
<?php if( get_option("couponpress_search_hover") == "off" || get_option("display_myaccount_fav") != "no"){ ?>
```

or

```
<?php if( get_option("couponpress_search_hover") == "off" && get_option("display_myaccount_fav") != "no"){ ?>
```

Comment: used both but not helped

Comment: http://mastapps.net/store-list/ its says you have no stores .. may be you should add sotores from backend

Comment: i mean stores are not related with this two options

Comment: login to admin check you have stores or not if not then add stores as you like then it will come up